# how do i set the value of a <select> tag from the database?

Tags: php, html

i am selecting an entry from the database to be edited on html/php. the code i wrote(from what i've learned) isn't working. i need a better and working one. i've searched google but all i see is only putting the default value for  tag.

```
    $civil_status = $row[8]; //value from selecting the database

    <tr> 
    <td>Civil Status:</td> 
    <td><select name="civil_status" value='<?php $civil_status ?>'>
    <option value="single">Single</option>
    <option value="married">Married</option>
    </select></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: ex. : `<option value="single" <?php if ($civil_status == 'single') { echo "selected"; } ?>>Single</option>`

Comment: <option value='<?php $civil_status ?>'>Single</option>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the quick-and-dirty way:

```
<tr>
    <td>Civil Status:</td> 
    <td>
        <select name="civil_status">
            <option value="single"<?php print($civil_status == "single" ? ' selected="selected"' : ""); ?>>Single</option>
            <option value="married"<?php print($civil_status == "married" ? ' selected="selected"' : ""); ?>>Married</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Or you can write a helper function for generating the entire `<option>` set:

```
function select_options($options, $selected)
{
    $result = "";
    foreach($options as $value => $label)
    {
         $result .= '<option value="' . 
             htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") . '"' . 
             ($selected == $value ? ' selected="selected"' : "") . '>' .
             htmlentities($label, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") . '</option>';
    }
    return $result;
}
```

**select_options** takes two parameters. The first is an associative array (`key => value, ...`) where the *array keys* are the `value` parameter values of the individual `<option>` tags, and the *array values* contain the labels to display for each key.

The second parameter specifies the `value` of the item to be selected in the select box.

The function then goes through the array and extracts the `value` and the `label` for every item. Then it appends the corresponding `<option>` tag to the result string. It also calls [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) on the parameters in order to avoid [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vulnerabilities.

And then comes the kicker: if it sees an item that should be selected in the select box (`$selected == $value`), it automatically appends the `selected="selected"` parameter to the `<option>` tag and thus selects that element.

To use the function, do the following:

```
<tr>
    <td>Civil Status:</td> 
    <td>
        <select name="civil_status">
            <?php
                  print(select_options(array(
                       "single" => "Single",
                       "married" => "Married"
                  ), $civil_status));
            ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Much cleaner and reusable anywhere you need to create a select menu.

Comment: wow! this code is cool, this is MVC right? i have not yet touched that technique but im gonna learn it. thanks man!!!

Comment: This code alone is not really MVC, just a handy helper method that works without MVC as well. But truth be told, I initially saw this solution in an MVC framework :)

Comment: i've tried this and its working but i have no idea how it works... thank you very much!

Comment: so this can be used for more than 2 options?

Comment: Sure, with any number of options.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `selected="selected"` in the option tag.Try like this

```
$civil_status = $row[8]; //value from selecting the database
    <tr> 
    <td>Civil Status:</td> 
    <td><select name="civil_status">
    <option value="single" <?php if($civil_status == 'Single') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Single</option>
    <option value="married" <?php if($civil_status == 'Married') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Married</option>
    </select></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: this code is working too! cool! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the option that you want to select and then print the selected tag:

```
$civil_status = $row[8]; //value from selecting the database
<tr> 
<td>Civil Status:</td> 
<td><select name="civil_status" >
<option value="single" <?php $civil_status=="single" ? print "selected" : ""; ?> >Single</option>
<option value="married" <?php $civil_status=="married" ? print "selected" : ""; ?> >Married</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Might be worth explaining the ternary operator too, the OP might not be familiar with it given the premise of the question.

Comment: his code is working, but yeah a little explaining would be good :) thanks btw!

Comment: 1) The default option in a select is in the option tag, not in select tag. 2) When I write short "if" statements, I prefer the ternary operator (expression) ? (true instruction) : (false instruction);

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
       <?php   
          $civil_status = $row[8]; //$civil_status ='married';
          $civil_statuses = array('single', 'married'); 
        ?>

        <select name="civil_status">
            <?php foreach($civil_statuses as $status){ ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $status;?>" <?php  echo if($civil_status==$status){ echo 'selected';} ?> ><?php echo ucfirst($status);?></option>
            <?php }?>
        </select>
```

Comment: this is working too but i need it to be reusable. thanks anyway!