# how do i set a value of a multiple <select> tag from the database

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am selecting an entry from the database to be edited on php/html. i can call the values of a table from the database and put it in a multiple  tag.

```
$job_exp_tags = $row[16];//value from another table
$job_tags = explode(',',$job_exp_tags);//array to be put "selected" on the multiple select tag

$sql_2 = "SELECT _id, job_name from job_tags";

    $sel_2 = mysql_query($sql_2);

    $array = array();

    while($row_new = mysql_fetch_assoc($sel_2)){

    $array[] = $row_new;


    }
<tr>
        <td>Job Experience:<br>
            (Hold ctrl to select multiple)</td>
        <td><select name = 'job_tags[]' multiple>
            <?php

            foreach($array as $value){ ?>

            <option value ='<?php echo $value['_id']; ?>'> <?php echo $value['job_name']; ?> </option>

            <?php

            }
            ?>
            </select> </td>
    </tr>
```

my problem is how can i put selected values to it from the explode statement

edit:

i've solved the problem, thanks anyway guys!

```
<option value ="<?php echo $value['_id']; ?>" <?php echo in_array($value['_id'], $job_tags) ? 'selected="true"' : null; ?>><?php echo $value['job_name']; ?></option>
```

Comment: Given that you say you get those job tags from a db, and then explode it, you're pretty much guaranteed to be using a  BAD database design. those values should be in their own child table, e.g.. you need normalize your tables. And then your question answers itself because you can do a simple JOIN query.

Comment: Duplicate of your own question [how do i set the value of a <select> tag from the database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768862/how-do-i-set-the-value-of-a-select-tag-from-the-database) – that it is a multiple select no doesn’t change much about how to do it.

Comment: @CBroe, its not its just a mistype of the title. sorry about that. gotta edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if its in your array, if so, set it selected:

```
foreach($array as $value){ ?>
    $selected = in_array($value, $job_tags) ? ' selected ' : '';
    /* Or [selected="selected"] if you dont use html5 yet (which you should) */

    <option value ='<?php echo $value['_id']; ?>' <?php echo $selected; ?>> <?php echo $value['job_name']; ?> </option>
    <?php
}
```

Your code can be simplified though:

```
foreach($array as $value){ 
    $selected = in_array($value, $job_tags) ? ' selected="selected" ' : ''; 
    ?>
    <option value="<?=$value['_id']?>" <?=$selected?> > <?=$value['job_name']?> </option>
    <?php
}
```

I changed the quotes arround the value to doubles, not really a rule, but it is a good practice to do so. The other change is the short echo. Small demo, both do the same:

```
<php $var = 'foorbar'; ?> <!-- A bit weird, but this is demo-purpose -->

<span><?php echo $var; ?></span>
<span><?=$var?></span>
```

Comment: Or just use `selected` instead of `selected="selected"` I think we've finally passed the XHTML era.

Comment: Some old habit :P I've changed it and added a bit of comment about it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could look for the value in the string $job_exp_tags and if found set the selected property.

```
foreach($array as $value){
    $selected = strpos($job_exp_tags, $value) ? 'selected' : '';
    echo '<option value="'.$value['_id'].'" '.$selected.'>'.$value['job_name'].'</option>';
}
```